# Why dereferencing user-space inside get_user is correct?

Tags: c, linux

For example, in the function `SYSCALL_DEFINE2` of linux kernel (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.3/source/arch/alpha/kernel/osf_sys.c#L657):

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(osf_proplist_syscall, enum pl_code, code,
        union pl_args __user *, args)
{
  long error;
  ...
  get_user(error, &args->set.nbytes)
  ...
}
```

Why it isn't need to use `copy_from_user` on `args` before using arrow and dot on it?

Comment: You `...`d out the actual name of the function!

Comment: I don't understand, function is actually called SYSCALL_DEFINE2

Comment: No it's not, SYSCALL_DEFINE2 is a macro that defines a function, the name of the function is the macro's first argument :) In this case it's `osf_proplist_syscall`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_user()` function will do actual copying from user space, so it will take care of the dangerous part. Take a good look at this:

`&args->set.nbytes`

What this actually does it not dereference any pointer, but just calculate new pointer value. Pointers are really just unsigned integer values. So the line above says: give me address of part of data that is some offset from the start of structure. Start of structure is `args` and offset is `set.nbytes`. No actual accessing of user space memory is required to do this.

Answer (score 2):

`&args->set.nbytes` is an *address*. It's allowed to compute the address of some member even if you couldn't actually read it — the compiler just adds the offset of the `set.nbytes` member of `union pl_args` to the address passed in `args`. Then it passes that address to `get_user`, which does the actual copying from userspace.